# Relation between Lebesgue measure of two sets

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

question in lebesgue measure:
Given that $T$ is a Jordan set of positive Lebesgue measure, $l(T)>0$. If $M \subset T $ such that $l(M)=0$ where $l(\cdot)$ denote Lebesgue measure, is it true relation that

$$
l(T)=l(T\backslash M)
$$
where $T\backslash M$ is the set $T$ excluding $M$.

Comment: Regarding the previous tags: [Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) has nothing to do with Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: in fact, for any Lebesgue measurable sets $A,B$ with $B \subseteq A$, we have
$$
\ell(A \setminus B) = \ell(A) - \ell(B)
$$
When $B$ has measure $0$ and $A$ is a Jordan set, we get the statement you were looking for.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, can you prove this result or can you refer me any book that has the proof of this relation.

Comment: This is a very standard result, and any text on measure theory should have a statement to this effect proven in there.  For a specific reference: the text I used was Strook's "A Concise Introduction to the Theory of Integration."